# python pillow _imaging.so undefined symbol: TIFFSetWarningHandlerExt error

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When i install pillow in my machine, pillow install successfully,
but when i use it like below:

from PIL import Image

Image.open(link)

_imaging throws error like below:

from . import _imaging as core

ImportError: /home/users/xyz/.jumbo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined symbol: TIFFSetWarningHandlerExt

in my machine, i only install pillow,

i do not  install PIL, pip list like below:

imageio (2.2.0)

itsdangerous (0.24)

jieba (0.39)

Jinja2 (2.9.6)

MarkupSafe (1.0)

meld3 (0.6.10)

MySQL-python (1.2.5)

numpy (1.12.1)

olefile (0.44)

Pillow (4.2.1)

pip (9.0.1)

pycurl (7.43.0)

PyMysqlPool (0.9)

setuptools (17.0)

supervisor (3.0a12)

Werkzeug (0.12.2)

my pillow version is  4.2.1,  Python 2.7.3

I search too many mathods, but I can not solve it, 
So I ask someone can help me ,
thank you!

Comment: could you please tell me your pillow version, i have Pillow (4.3.0) and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

if your version .so mismatch,maybe jumbo python cause.

if your python >= 2.7


try these:

> pip install http://effbot.org/media/downloads/Imaging-1.1.6.tar.gz

this work for me !please feedback for me~

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try update libtiff:

download link: http://download.osgeo.org/libtiff/

```
$ tar zxvf tiff-3.9.7.tar.gz
$ cd tiff-3.9.7
$ ./configure && make clean && make && make install
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
```